# EditText allows anything after changing inputType programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have an **editText** that accepts only numbers.
I have 4 types that goes into it: Date, Year, Math, Trivia.
I use a checkbox to switch between these types.

**InputType** changes like this:

- Date: null(the user will tap on the editText to choose a date) Year,
- Math, Trivia: signed_number

By default, input type is set to Trivia and I can type only numbers, but when I switch between my types at least once, I'm able to type anything. It works correctly only on Date type.

The listener that handle all this:

```kt
rgType.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
        val checked = findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)
        numType = when (checked.text) {
            "Year" -> NumType.YEAR
            "Date" -> NumType.DATE
            "Math" -> NumType.MATH
            else -> NumType.TRIVIA
        }

        tNumber.setText("")
        tAnswer.text = ""
        when (numType) {
            NumType.DATE -> {
                tNumber.hint = "CHOOSE A DATE"
                tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
                tNumber.hideKeyboard()
            }
            NumType.YEAR -> {
                tNumber.hint = "TYPE A YEAR"
                tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                tNumber.hideKeyboard()
            }
            else -> {
                tNumber.hint = "TYPE A NUMBER"
                tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                tNumber.hideKeyboard()
            }
        }
        Log.d("Input", tNumber.inputType.toString())
    }
```

**UPDATED CODE: **

```kt
rgType.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
        val checked = findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)
        numType = when (checked.text) {
            "Year" -> NumType.YEAR
            "Date" -> NumType.DATE
            "Math" -> NumType.MATH
            else -> NumType.TRIVIA
        }

        tNumber.setText("")
        tAnswer.text = ""
        when (numType) {
            NumType.DATE -> {
                tNumber.hint = "CHOOSE A DATE"
                tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
                tNumber.hideKeyboard()
            }
            NumType.YEAR -> {
                tNumber.hint = "TYPE A YEAR"
                tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                tNumber.hideKeyboard()
            }
            else -> {
                tNumber.hint = "TYPE A NUMBER"
                tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                tNumber.hideKeyboard()
            }
        }
        Log.d("Input", tNumber.inputType.toString())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 4 input types:

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
```

All others are flags. If you want to set flags, you have to use the `or` operator.
Examples:

```
tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME or InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE

tNumber.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
```

Comment: It works, thanks.
But how do I set the one with no input?

Comment: `InputType.TYPE_NULL` also is a valid type

Comment: There is a strange bug, even though it is null, sometimes I can write in the editText.

Comment: Can you tell the steps to reproduce the bug?

Comment: If I switch between types while typing.

Comment: add this `tNumber.isFocusable = false` after setting the input type to null

Comment: I can't make it focusable again after that.
It doesn't seem to work.
I've added in else and numType.YEAR `tNumber.isFocusable = true`

Comment: wait, if the keyboard is hidden, how you can write in the editText? looks like your hideKeyboard() function not work

Comment: I'm using the emulator. I'm typing from the pc keyboard.
hideKeyboard() works fine.

Comment: instead of  set the input type to null you can try this `tNumber.isEnabled = false`

Comment: can't click on it if I do that.

Comment: I think I'll put an invisible button on top of my tNumber when the type is date.
That way will be easier.

Comment: try this `isFocusable = false` and to make it focusable again use `isFocusableInTouchMode = true; isFocusable = true`